# MSB6003 clang.exe could not be run

Tags: c++, build-error

I have a small C++ project in Visual Studio based on the cross platform OpenGLES2 template. I didn't have any problems until I suddenly started to get this compilation error:

```
MSB6003 The specified task executable "clang.exe" could not be run. The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
```

There are no changes in the code before and after I started to get the error. I've tried to clean the solution and rebuild, restart VS and restart the computer.

I've googled the problem, but I can't seem to find anything that works or understandable solution. Though it seem to be related to some environment variables? But do they change for no reason?

What is "clang.exe" and where should it be located?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.

As the error stated "*The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.*", some files were actually corrupted. By trying to delete some files in the project folder, I got an error from Windows stating the files were corrupt. (Why? I don't know how it happened.)

I created a new project based on the same template, and copied over my source code. Luckily none of my source code was *corrupt*!